# gstreamer playbin - setting uri on windows

Tags: python, gstreamer

I am trying to play some audio files with the CLI example on this site:

http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/playbin.html
http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/playbin.html

I am on windows and it is giving error while reading the file. I specified
the following path:

```
$ python cliplayer.py C:\\voice.mp3

0:00:00.125000000  3788   009DA010 ERROR                basesrc
gstbasesrc.c:2834:gst_base_src_activate_pull:<source> Failed to start in
pull mode
Error: Could not open resource for reading.
..\..\..\Source\gst-plugins-base\ext\gio\gstgiosrc.c(324):
gst_gio_src_get_stream ():
/GstPlayBin2:player/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstGioSrc:source:
Could not open location file:///C:/file:/C:/voice.mp3 for reading: Error
opening file: Invalid argument
```

How should I specify the file path on windows??

Also, is there anything special I need to do in this line of code?

```
self.player.set_property("uri", "file://" + filepath)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you may have suspected, this code is rather badly written:

```
for filepath in sys.argv[1:]:
    # ...
    self.player.set_property("uri", "file://" + filepath)
```

Use something like this:

```
'file:' + urllib.pathname2url(filepath)
```

and (in the command line) specify the file path in normal Windows notation, e.g. `C:\a\b.mp3`.

Comment: urllib.pathname2url is a good suggestion... I haven't tried it but looks like it will work... btw there is another method filename_to_uri... didn't check what it does, but should convert the path to uri... . on the other hand, file:/// (triple slashes) fixed the issue for me on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Did you notice the actual path you've got is `file:///C:/file:/C:/voice.mp3`?

The correct path should be: `file:///C:/path/to/voice.mp3`.