# gstreamer uri format on windows

Tags: uri, gstreamer, gst-launch

I am trying to play media files with gstreamer ,mp3 currently  but I am getting the uri format wrong and it can't find the file.

The original command from [the documentation](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/faq/html/chapter-using.html) is

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/joe/my-random-media-file.mpeg
```

I am trying to make it work on windows and writing

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file://C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\bin\pima.mp3
```

This is the output I am getting

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstGioSrc:source: Could not open  resource       for    reading.
Additional debug info:
gstgiosrc.c(332): gst_gio_src_get_stream (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstGioSrc:source:
**Could not open location file:///C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/bin/file:/pima.avi for reading: Error opening file: Invalid argument**
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

Can anybody help on how I can get around this ?

I also tried to play mp3 files using

```
gst-launch filesrc location=hello.mp3 ! mad ! audioresample ! osssink
```

but found out that osssink was not installed .How can I get it installed or any other sink that can play mp3 files. A piece of advice on how I can figure out my own gstElements to build pipelines would be very helpful .For example how can I go about playing avi videos.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216064/gstreamer-playbin-setting-uri-on-windows I found out that I heeded to use triple slashes like this :gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/bin/pima.mp3

Comment: Great that you figured it out yourself. However, you might want post your solution as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax worked for me :

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///C:/gstreamer/1.0/x86/bin/pima.mp3
```