# What are valid gstreamer song names?

Tags: python, gstreamer

I'm trying to understand what song names can I use in my gstreamer python based audioplayer. Can't find any docs about it. For example song with name `test%.mp3` produce the error:

```
Error: [<GError at 0x7f8a8c001620>, 'gstgiosrc.c(324): gst_gio_src_get_stream (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstGioSrc:source:\nCould not open location file:///home/austinnikov/work/daemon_player/program_root/test%.mp3 for reading: Operation not supported'],
```

Songs without `%` are played. And of cause I have `test%.mp3` on the hard drive in that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following SO answer:[[Solved]gstreamer uri format on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092616/solvedgstreamer-uri-format-on-windows)
specifically the `'file:' + urllib.pathname2url(filepath)` part.
While this does not answer your more general question, it does permit you to play files which include certain characters like `%`

Answer (score 0):

Rolf's answer is great, but I wanted to add that if your songs_names are in unicode as mine then `pathname2url` will fail with `KeyError`. So I did it in slightly another way, note also [Convert a filename to a file:// URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687478/convert-a-filename-to-a-file-url).
This function is a part of `Player` class. `Player` instance has `player` variable `self.player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin")`:

```
def set_song(self, song_name):
    song_name = song_name.encode('utf8')
    path = urlparse.urljoin("file://", urllib.pathname2url(song_name))
    path = path.decode('utf8')
    self.player.set_property("uri", path))
```

And now I'm pretty happy cause my song names can be in unicode and contain any weird symbols.